# RSA public key generation from modulus and exponent(unknown encoding)

Tags: rsa, digital-signature

I have an xml containing digital signature and its public key(modulus and exponent), here is the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="dsig-20200803161917094-7">
    <SignedInfo>
        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11" />
        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
        <Reference URI="#scap_gov.nist_datastream_R800-Windows">
            <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <DigestValue>gGZCC97H5Q6uFzel0Ucs1hY/9SuVmGUa7r62ffrKVc4=</DigestValue>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#SignatureProperties" URI="#sig-props-20200803161917110-72">
            <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha512" />
            <DigestValue>ZlDYhlZnsKMm1QVdvwL/5vNQByuuSjDN9Mg+GF5ocbCJ5/PAaUGi3P9XbZv+Z0JUxWxuybqOEcaE
    O4Khtb8XAA==</DigestValue>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#Manifest" URI="#manifest-20200803161917094-45">
            <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <DigestValue>1+X01cf+LMDlQ5W0HKH1A6j+XPaltsv6q6/kpWfwfY0=</DigestValue>
        </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>LXVodm30DHPnJ1pIal/A9YlC3xRRXJHfge48I2K9G3gdubl92ryTiGSZhrND1Oy/14CmOLihPAfo
    pHDZ21r3ybvrg7mC0JBEY+03aE+ezarGUBKxo+HpEWGIY+GoBOnovrwMtNbAWR0y7FArXGSQ5y7a
    ektbvc+sTcn3cYVvABfJAUA7A4zLDrTkzsO3Mpmixl/93QS+SB430V2AnLdPiDeRD7WQJGHHQzze
    jfp0DziR1HORKBTmphnr8J2ycyEvy0Fa7+pdW5a0PDH3dRczij3JWhnPlz6il4iqDWJurfjRR8Vy
    Uas6YNxmy7swDXfPOdsCVneK0RV4r1s7HOjdAA==</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
        <KeyValue>
            <RSAKeyValue>
                <Modulus>wmfGdxpS5t+Lzlx+XqkGl+kSUoD3KsXevJKiphzT8F8KEJTJmeklHMbKQGtTwN58z4LrJY+G1adh
    olGCeGC/x1NemCR7JTGhvo3MusZUjKzbRTXjfxLowBGDeHpk/6l3y3VoKBRurUQZ0CIsHenhfqRJ
    dkvexPtC/+/46xigaPyWZfc/F4c2mPMr2Sbe2UhDUHzGM0skpjH9dDl/vPBrIe/lfqVwTKDi+bKe
    K4DZxs+ZT0mPL+UVKLlATARVGD9IbrHt+AXi75GEsWHmQEIzUKdDOMwawL8eRaStbGQKs1OWFv5R
    lSH7D9MYWuDW5fM220CXKn/dnDMsa9gZePMtvQ==</Modulus>
                <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
            </RSAKeyValue>
        </KeyValue>
        <X509Data>
            <X509SubjectName>CN=content.scap.nist.gov,OU=ITL/CSD,O=National Institute of Standards and Technology,L=Gaithersburg,ST=Maryland,C=US</X509SubjectName>
            <X509SKI>BBYEFI3AalwT/wCNGneelXoUf+V9Zic9</X509SKI>
            <X509IssuerSerial>
                <X509IssuerName>CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US</X509IssuerName>
                <X509SerialNumber>2646203786665923649276728595390119057</X509SerialNumber>
            </X509IssuerSerial>
            <X509Certificate>MIIGWzCCBUOgAwIBAgIQCcWQAP1t1eZ/09fSRlW7/zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBNMQswCQYDVQQG
    EwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMScwJQYDVQQDEx5EaWdpQ2VydCBTSEEyIFNlY3Vy
    ZSBTZXJ2ZXIgQ0EwHhcNMjAwMTA5MDAwMDAwWhcNMjEwMTA5MTIwMDAwWjCBojELMAkGA1UEBhMC
    VVMxETAPBgNVBAgTCE1hcnlsYW5kMRUwEwYDVQQHEwxHYWl0aGVyc2J1cmcxNzA1BgNVBAoTLk5h
    dGlvbmFsIEluc3RpdHV0ZSBvZiBTdGFuZGFyZHMgYW5kIFRlY2hub2xvZ3kxEDAOBgNVBAsTB0lU
    TC9DU0QxHjAcBgNVBAMTFWNvbnRlbnQuc2NhcC5uaXN0LmdvdjCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAD
    ggEPADCCAQoCggEBAMJnxncaUubfi85cfl6pBpfpElKA9yrF3rySoqYc0/BfChCUyZnpJRzGykBr
    U8DefM+C6yWPhtWnYaJRgnhgv8dTXpgkeyUxob6NzLrGVIys20U1438S6MARg3h6ZP+pd8t1aCgU
    bq1EGdAiLB3p4X6kSXZL3sT7Qv/v+OsYoGj8lmX3PxeHNpjzK9km3tlIQ1B8xjNLJKYx/XQ5f7zw
    ayHv5X6lcEyg4vmyniuA2cbPmU9Jjy/lFSi5QEwEVRg/SG6x7fgF4u+RhLFh5kBCM1CnQzjMGsC/
    HkWkrWxkCrNTlhb+UZUh+w/TGFrg1uXzNttAlyp/3ZwzLGvYGXjzLb0CAwEAAaOCAt8wggLbMB8G
    A1UdIwQYMBaAFA+AYRyCMWHVLyjnjUY4tCzhxtniMB0GA1UdDgQWBBSNwGpcE/8AjRp3npV6FH/l
    fWYnPTAgBgNVHREEGTAXghVjb250ZW50LnNjYXAubmlzdC5nb3YwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgWgMB0G
    A1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjBrBgNVHR8EZDBiMC+gLaArhilodHRwOi8vY3Js
    My5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vc3NjYS1zaGEyLWc2LmNybDAvoC2gK4YpaHR0cDovL2NybDQuZGlnaWNl
    cnQuY29tL3NzY2Etc2hhMi1nNi5jcmwwTAYDVR0gBEUwQzA3BglghkgBhv1sAQEwKjAoBggrBgEF
    BQcCARYcaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tL0NQUzAIBgZngQwBAgIwfAYIKwYBBQUHAQEE
    cDBuMCQGCCsGAQUFBzABhhhodHRwOi8vb2NzcC5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20wRgYIKwYBBQUHMAKGOmh0
    dHA6Ly9jYWNlcnRzLmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbS9EaWdpQ2VydFNIQTJTZWN1cmVTZXJ2ZXJDQS5jcnQw
    CQYDVR0TBAIwADCCAQIGCisGAQQB1nkCBAIEgfMEgfAA7gB1ALvZ37wfinG1k5Qjl6qSe0c4V5UK
    q1LoGpCWZDaOHtGFAAABb4vPJ3oAAAQDAEYwRAIgGcw2hZ+7LgR1q2ByPgWK18cPNG7PTJlXWeEG
    GzMptNICIFtIHX5dPCo43lJvWlXHIaPfGp7l12HShO1WG2z2UpThAHUARJRlLrDuzq/EQAfYqP4o
    wNrmgr7YyzG1P9MzlrW2gagAAAFvi88nIQAABAMARjBEAiBr20vLOkDlMfwA+x2p/nfe5PFJKjAP
    ozwCkc2F0vQ6nwIgNZihBoYxYj139/RpkharFR0GTp+KeuFcrTngeFk1CyQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
    BQADggEBAIz+fmBSfcFgLbrVM1k9PzKkZyyATLRqkCaXiHbVBZ7lN9VH8U5fqLjvflisKMPJS2zq
    ztINspnYVzqHasbI7aYr0UG50ssxYRAMn1ROcGtwsLZpTfu0x0omHXfMrmE4n2KTl1fsqsOGUeee
    22IpbIe/UG56J83e0TDRdb1rDhUqsK/tlQXPuW70me5IlQ2/j0cmIdPA0HEY7Sp0QEdAO/XD62bl
    cFM6JH52GAoAWTLUHEBIUlQy2xs73f1F2AAajVmC0Zp0D8/QnF1xkFkhfYqV1jMqxozN4HZRCB15
    fGUxNnfJBlnty8PQ9zLA9JYJxiKAdrN0amXzXzhTBuYXE8g=</X509Certificate>
        </X509Data>
        <X509Data>
            <X509SubjectName>CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US</X509SubjectName>
            <X509SKI>BBYEFA+AYRyCMWHVLyjnjUY4tCzhxtni</X509SKI>
            <X509Certificate>MIIElDCCA3ygAwIBAgIQAf2j627KdciIQ4tyS8+8kTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBhMQswCQYDVQQG
    EwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMSAw
    HgYDVQQDExdEaWdpQ2VydCBHbG9iYWwgUm9vdCBDQTAeFw0xMzAzMDgxMjAwMDBaFw0yMzAzMDgx
    MjAwMDBaME0xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRUwEwYDVQQKEwxEaWdpQ2VydCBJbmMxJzAlBgNVBAMTHkRp
    Z2lDZXJ0IFNIQTIgU2VjdXJlIFNlcnZlciBDQTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoC
    ggEBANyuWJBNwcQwFZA1W248ghX1LFy949v/cUP6ZCWA1O4Yok3wZtAKc24RmDYXZK83nf36QYSv
    x6+M/hpzTc8zl5CilodTgyu5pnVILR1WN3vaMTIa16yrBvSqXUu3R0bdKpPDkC55gIDvEwRqFDu1
    m5K+wgdlTvza/P96rtxcflUxDOg5B6TXvi/TC2rSsd9f/ld0Uzs1gN2ujkSYs58O09rg1/RrKatE
    p0tYhG2SS4HD2nOLEpdIkARFdRrdNzGXkujNVA075ME/OV4uuPNcfhCOhkEAjUVmR7ChZc6gqikJ
    TvOX6+guqw9ypzAO+sf0/RR3w6RbKFfCs/mC/bdFWJsCAwEAAaOCAVowggFWMBIGA1UdEwEB/wQI
    MAYBAf8CAQAwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgGGMDQGCCsGAQUFBwEBBCgwJjAkBggrBgEFBQcwAYYYaHR0
    cDovL29jc3AuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMHsGA1UdHwR0MHIwN6A1oDOGMWh0dHA6Ly9jcmwzLmRpZ2lj
    ZXJ0LmNvbS9EaWdpQ2VydEdsb2JhbFJvb3RDQS5jcmwwN6A1oDOGMWh0dHA6Ly9jcmw0LmRpZ2lj
    ZXJ0LmNvbS9EaWdpQ2VydEdsb2JhbFJvb3RDQS5jcmwwPQYDVR0gBDYwNDAyBgRVHSAAMCowKAYI
    KwYBBQUHAgEWHGh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbS9DUFMwHQYDVR0OBBYEFA+AYRyCMWHV
    LyjnjUY4tCzhxtniMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFAPeUDVW0Uy7ZvCj4hsbw5eyPdFVMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB
    CwUAA4IBAQAjPt9L0jFCpbZ+QlwaRMxp0Wi0XUvgBCFsS+JtzLHgl4+mUwnNqipl5TlPHoOlblyY
    oiQm5vuh7ZPHLgLGTUq/sELfeNqzqPlt/yGFUzZgTHbO7Djc1lGA8MXW5dRNJ2Srm8c+cftIl7gz
    bckTB+6WohsYFfZcTEDts8Ls/3HB40f/1LkAtDdC2iDJ6m6K7hQGrn2iWZiIqBtvLfTyyRRfJs8s
    jX7tN8Cp1Tm5gr8ZDOo0rwAhaPitc+LJMto4JQtV05od8GiG7S5BNO98pVAdvzr508EIDObtHopY
    JeS4d60tbvVS3bR0j6tJLp07kzQoH3jOlOrHvdPJbRzeXDLz</X509Certificate>
        </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
    <Object>
        <SignatureProperties Id="sig-props-20200803161917110-72">
            <SignatureProperty Target="#dsig-20200803161917094-7">
                <dsig:signature-info xmlns:dsig="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/xml-dsig/1.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
                <dc:date>2020-08-03T16:19:17-0400</dc:date>
                <dsig:nonce>16c076c903281f31</dsig:nonce>
                </dsig:signature-info>
            </SignatureProperty>
        </SignatureProperties>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <Manifest Id="manifest-20200803161917094-45">
            <Reference URI="#scap_gov.nist_comp_r800-windows-cpe-dictionary.xml">
                <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>vAmKNDsNgz8V1Ndo2FOlPfwuKa9oul24jPeNPgjy2Jk=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
            <Reference URI="#scap_gov.nist_comp_r800-windows-xccdf.xml">
                <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>6iYOz8HfKm48JxU2A5u8qYGduKqfZrBSBKGtXqwW9kg=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
            <Reference URI="#scap_gov.nist_comp_r800-windows-oval.xml">
                <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>znt/X+dX8pXZDAnv5SyntoivxMFI+BWf3WXy0CdFe9s=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
            <Reference URI="#scap_gov.nist_comp_r800-windows-cpe-oval.xml">
                <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>qxtBufC6djby3CeKzJyqHDCham09gw/h2xqhqKrCdbA=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
            <Reference URI="#scap_gov.nist_comp_r800-windows-patches.xml">
                <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>Qq9LAnENWSjD/1LyVj9LIc5zxsu1L/L6paYCebg9cRk=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </Manifest>
    </Object>
</Signature>
```

I am trying to generate the public key using the modulus and exponent(my end goal is to verify the signature with the public key, but this xml does not have public key directly given). what I thought was these are in base64 encoded and I should decode them and generate the public key out of it, but when I try to decode them with base64 I get garbage text, here is the text I am getting for decoding in base64 for modulus in the xml

```
gwR\~^R*_
%@kS|%aQx`S^${%1TE5xzdwuh(nD",~IvKBhe?6+&HCP|3K$1t9k!~pL+OI/(@LU?Hna@B3PC8Eld
SQ!Z6@*3,kx-
```

At this point I am not really sure if it was base64 encoded text or something. Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Yes [XMLdsig uses base64](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core2/#sec-RSAKeyValue); the RSA elements (n=modulus and e=pubexpt, and also the signature) are not text, they are numbers represented as arbitrary octets (bytes), which is why they are _encoded_ in base64 to allow handling in XML which is designed for text. Software designed to handle XMLdsig should already handle this representation without any change; for other software there are a dozen different representations of publickeys and you don't say which you want. FWIW, JOSE/JWS/JWK would be the easiest.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for your input, I was trying this manually, probably that isn't the right way. I am new to this, wasn't sure on how verify this signature. It would really helpful if you can point me to a source that I could verify this signature with pubkey in python or any other language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know it was this simple, just went through [chilkat](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/python.asp) library, it did all the work for me. I didn't had to extract the keys and all, it just took the file and verified it.